# Custom messages in logging for failing tests with Geb/Spock?

Tags: spock, geb

I'm busy with an e2e test in Geb/Spock, I was wondering how I can add custom messages. 
Now I only get a stacktrace like this:

```
geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page content 'pages.patientConversation.PcModal -> contact: geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' is not present
    at geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent.require(TemplateDerivedPageContent.groovy:60)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create_closure1(PageContentTemplate.groovy:63)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create_closure1(PageContentTemplate.groovy)
```

etc ...

This is an example of my test:

```
 def "allow for searching contacts"() {
    when:
    to LoginPage
    login(emailAddress, defaultPassword)
    then:
    at QuickBar
    when:
    startButton.click()
    then:
    at Modal
    when:
    selectContactButton.click()
    contactSearchField.value(context.pcUser2.surname)
    then: "the contact is shown in the search results"
    contact.isDisplayed()
}
```

I figured the text "the contact is shown in the search results"  would be present in the error message, but apparently it doesn't. Is there maybe another way in Geb of Spock to print custom messages for more clarity?

Especially for 'at checkers' I would like to have custom messages, because when an at check fails, you only get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: geb.error.GebAssertionError.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

at geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException.<init>
```

etc

EDIT:
Hmmm I realize now, the test failed because it also checks for the required page content, before doing the "then". Still I would like the ability to add custom messages (especially for 'at checkers') ... Does anybody know if that is possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [custom-message](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#custom-message) to add a custom message to  `WaitTimeoutException`

```
class HomePage extends Page {

    static at = {
        waitFor(message:"My custom message")    {title == "Acme Corporation"}
        waitFor(message:"My custom message",20) {$("#roadRunner")}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And when I want to give a custom message for regular "a==b" stuff? That's probably more of a Spock question.

Comment: You can use assert message
```then:
assert a == b : "My custome message"
```

Comment: Thanks. To bad you still need "assert" in that case, because I thought the power of Spock was implicit asserts

Comment: Hmmmmm it still does not work though ... when I intentionally make a mistake (for instance a id that doesn't exist), it only shows the NoSuchMethodError ...

Comment: Did you try ```assert $("#id").isDisplayed() : "My custome message"```

Comment: That does work, but when I do: `at = { waitFor(message:"Custom message!") { $('#faultyId') } }` in a page object and in the test `at SomePage`, it does not work. Similarly when an element is part of the content of a page object and set wait to "true" and I do `assert anElement.isDisplayed(): "Custom message"` in the test,  it doesn't seem to work (sorry, should have been more elaborate).